# Using impedance to get RLC Transfer Function

Tags: circuit-analysis, transfer-function, laplace-transform

[image]
I am trying to get the transfer function G(s)=Vo(s)/VI(s) of this circuit and I am lost. I know that in the s domain, L=sL and C=1/sC. I tried to calculate it already and got R+(Ls)/((Ls^2)*C+1). But I don't know if that is correct because I didn't really do anything with current?

I think I am confused on the overall method of getting a transfer function for a circuit. I thought the steps were get Vi, manipulate it until the right is in terms of Vo, and then do Laplace, and then put into Vo/Vi form. But I am seeing around this forum another method where you use impedance somehow? That is what I attempted to use to get my top answer, impedance of R + Xc || XL. I tried looking at other RLC circuit transfer functions on here where that method was used and I did not understand what the process is.

So how am I supposed to calculate this?

Comment: I see i(t) there. Are you looking to get time-domain? Or s-domain? Or both?

Comment: I am looking to get s-domain. That was just me trying to figure out what to do with current. I broke down the voltages into their parts like i(t)R and L*(di/dt) and then took the Laplace of those and of course because it is a current divider all of the currents are different and it made me more confused.

Comment: If I use sagemath/sympy and define this function for parallel use: `def par(a,b):return a*b/(a+b)`. Then `ratsimp(par(1/s/c1,s*l1)/(r1+par(1/s/c1,s*l1)))` gives `l1*s/(c1*l1*r1*s**2 + l1*s + r1)`. It's really just the same as the usual voltage divider equation except that you use the impedance form for the C and L parts. Otherwise, it's all just the same algebraic manipulation. Or you could use KCL: `solve(Eq(vout/r1+vout/(1/s/c1)+vout/(s*l1),vin/r1),vout)[0]/vin` and get `l1*s/(c1*l1*r1*s**2 + l1*s + r1)`. Same answer, different method. That's the wonderful thing about Laplace. Easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I am confused on the overall method of getting a transfer function for
> a circuit*

You analyse it like you would a [potential divider made from resistors](https://study.com/academy/lesson/voltage-divider-circuit-rule-bias-formula.html): -

[image]

The lower resistor is, in effect, the parallel impedance of the capacitor and inductor. The upper resistor is \$R\$ in your circuit.

- Calculate \$\dfrac{1}{sC}\$ in parallel with \$sL\$ (call it \$Z\$ if you want)
- Use the potential divider formula to get the TF = \$\dfrac{Z}{R+Z}\$

> *how am I supposed to calculate this?*

Use the above method and drill down to you get a solution. A quick calculation tells me it is: -

$$TF = \dfrac{s\frac{1}{CR}}{s^2 + s\frac{1}{CR} +\frac{1}{LC}}$$

Comment: Ah ok- so the method is basically you skip making a t-domain equation and then doing Laplace on it, instead you start from the s-domain versions of the circuit components and then just use basic circuit analysis? Like for your answer, you just did a basic potential divider but with the s-domain impedances instead of t-domain?

Comment: @book correct. See also this wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider

Comment: Is your final answer correct? I put [(sL/sC)/((1/sC)+sL)] / [R + (sL/sC)/((1/sC)+sL)] into a calculator and I got (sL)/[(s^2)RLC+R+sL], same as periblepsis.

Comment: @book That's the same as mine except I manipulated into standard form as an extra step. Standard form resolves damping ratio and natural resonant frequency. I always take this step and it's use for you to learn that too (if you are interested).

Comment: Ohh, I didn't know about standard form. What makes your answer in standard form? Thank you so much for all of your help.

Comment: Try researching damping factor and natural resonant frequency. Maybe Khan will help: https://www.khanacademy.org/science/electrical-engineering/ee-circuit-analysis-topic/ee-natural-and-forced-response/a/ee-rlc-natural-response-variations

Comment: Maybe this might help also: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/162100/standard-form-of-2nd-order-transfer-function-laplace-transform

Comment: @book, At least **these** standard forms for 2nd order bandpass:$$\begin{align*}\frac{\frac1{Q}\,\omega_{_0}s}{s^2+\frac1{Q}\,\omega_{_0}s+\omega_{_0}^{\,2}}&&
\frac{2\zeta\,\omega_{_0}s}{s^2+2\zeta\,\omega_{_0}s+\omega_{_0}^{\,2}}&&\frac{\frac1{Q}\left(\frac{s}{\omega_{_0}}\right)}{\left(\frac{s}{\omega_{_0}}\right)^2+\frac1{Q}\left(\frac{s}{\omega_{_0}}\right)+1}
\\\\
\frac{2\zeta\left(\frac{s}{\omega_{_0}}\right)}{\left(\frac{s}{\omega_{_0}}\right)^2+2\zeta\left(\frac{s}{\omega_{_0}}\right)+1}&&\frac{1}{1+Q\left(\frac{s}{\omega_{_0}}+\frac{\omega_{_0}}{s}\right)}
\end{align*}$$Oh well.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply the fast analytical circuits techniques or FACTs as described in my last [book](https://stairwaypress.com/product/fast-track/) on the subject and you won't write a line of algebra in this example. Determine the time constants involving the capacitor and the inductor when the input voltage is set to 0 V. Then determine high-frequency gains when each energy-storing element - the cap. and the inductor - are alternatively set in their high-frequency state. Assemble the results, re-arrange and voilà, you have your transfer function:

[image]

One important thing is to rearrange the transfer function - always - so that it unveils salient points like gain, resonant frequencies and quality factor, as with this 2nd-order polynomial form. You solve a transfer function for design-oriented analysis (D-OA), to later use the expression for calculating components values.

Comment: Damn. You keep writing books. I just bought this one, today, through the seller you linked. Best wishes! Thanks for your contributions not just here but elsewhere as well. (If you ever get crazy enough to retire to the wild west of the US, western Oregon where all manner of food grows fast and easy, I'll set you up with a nice home at my expense. My honor and privilege.)

Comment: Hello *periblepsis*, yes, another book is out but another one is cooking, on control loop but more practical than the 2012 one. I am an outdoor and mountains guy (I love fishing, mountain biking, hiking...) and I'm sure Oregon would be an excellent place to retire! Thank you for the very kind offer : )

Comment: I'll keep an eye out for the next one! (Teasing you: I live on a mountain area -- Mt Hood which rises almost 4 km from surroundings -- and we have mountain lions, deer, wild rabbits, and a great many species of birds here. A mountain lion only recently walked about 4 m from where my wife was hanging clothes. Just sauntered by casually. Didn't scare my wife. Fishing everywhere here, within hiking distance, wind surfing, thousands of km hiking to do, geology, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, using the voltage divider formula:

$$\mathscr{H}\left(\text{s}\right):=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{o}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)}=\frac{\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}}\space\text{||}\space\text{sL}}{\displaystyle\text{R}+\left(\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}}\space\text{||}\space\text{sL}\right)}=\frac{\displaystyle\text{sL}}{\displaystyle\text{CLRs}^2+\text{Ls}+\text{R}}\tag1$$

Where \$\displaystyle\alpha\space\text{||}\space\beta:=\frac{\displaystyle\alpha\beta}{\displaystyle\alpha+\beta}\$.